# Why it this code triggering a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I am getting `Segmentation Fault` for the following code which is weird cuz I don't see where I am accessing un-initialized memory. I have tried to debug the code and found that this segmentation fault has something to do with `*g` inside thread procedure. Here is the code:

```
void *Func(void *arg);

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    void *x;

    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,Func,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid,&x);
    int i=*(int *)x;
    printf("Data returned from the thread %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}

void *Func(void *arg)
{
    int *g;
    int i=2,j=3;
    printf("inside thread\n");      
    *g=i+j;
    printf("%d\n",*g);

    return g;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the code below

```
int *g;
....
*g=i+j;
```

`g` is an uninitialised pointer.  When you dereference it, you are trying to write to an undefined location in memory.  The effects of this are undefined but a seg fault is very likely.

There are a number of ways you could address this, including

- allocate memory for `g`
- point `g` towards some allocated memory
- declare `g` on the stack in `main` and pass a pointer to it into your child thread

Comment: cant we directly do *g=5; for a static local pointer variable

Comment: @Alfred A static pointer still won't point to an address of memory you can safely write to. I've updated my answer to include some options for how you could fix your seg fault.

Answer (score 2):

in `int *g;`  g is an address of location that is not allocated and you are trying to assigned on that location.

do like this:

`int *g=calloc(1, sizeof(int)) ;`

Also don't forget to `free` memory.

Comment: yeah it was confusing because a similar alloca.h does exist which is not portable and allocates on the stack. So first thought i had was, is there an equivalent calloca or something

Comment: ha ha...yesterday only i came to know about this `not portable and allocates` ..Thanks ..I corrected my code

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
int *g;
...
*g=i+j;
```

`g` is an uninitialized pointer and you are trying to write to the location it is pointing to, which leads to undefined behavior.